# How to detect a (very) small change in the position of a needle?

Tags: measurement

I am very sorry if my question is too basic (or odd), but I do not know anything about electrical engineering.

I would like to mimic the motion-sensing filiform hairs in spiders and insects:
[image: filiform hairs diagram]

The hair is loosely suspended in a socket, and as it moves, it stimulates a nerve. Basically, it comes down to detecting a very small change in the position of a needle.

My intention would be to use the results to measure air flow in an HVAC vent, so a carpet of these hairs would be dropped into a vent, which would then give readings on flow across the surface.

The constraints would be rough handling (it would be rolled/unrolled, bent, etc). It should also be easy to clean.

My ideal answer would be a link to a device, tool, or circuit that does a very similar thing, or a (very simple) explanation of what you would do to mimic this measurement. I am trying to find the most cost-effective means possible.

Thank you!

PS. I've already looked at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66545/measuring-very-small-changes-in-resistor-network-using-current-source), but I do not understand the diagrams.

PPS. Here is an [article on the biology](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/6/40/1047).

Comment: You should describe your requirements and constraints more precisely.

Comment: Micro-motion is typically done with piezoelectric sensors, both as a sensor and motor (of sorts) Shop online as there are many, some can sense millionths of an inch. Billionths if you can afford them.

Comment: @Sparky256 - Thank you! That looks really promising!

Comment: @NeilMussett. Your welcome, but this could be an expensive project. Once you resolve issues down to the electronics, including Eugene's comment, then we can help you more directly. It is up to you to decide what the best sensor is-and its range.

Comment: If you look into [MEMS technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems), there are many ways to detect tiny movements, the most common being silicon strain gauges and interdigitated capacitors. Indeed, inexpensive differential pressure gauges that are already used to measure airflow are based on this technology. I'm not sure why you think that a "carpet of hairs" would be better in some way.

Comment: An LVDT (differential transformer) would have the least resistance to tiny motions, but in terms of cost vs. performance I could be splitting hairs here. Besides, it is only a measuring tool, as far as I know.

Comment: This is essentially how [atomic force microscopy (AFM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic-force_microscopy) works. In AFM, I believe the motion is detected by reflecting a laser beam off a reflector on the other end of the needle, and watching how the reflected beam moves on a target some distance away. This method can measure needle deflections below 1 nm.

Comment: I have never seen spiders which could be rolled, bent, or were easy to clean.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to mimic the **motion-sensing** filiform hairs in spiders and insects.

I think you have unwittingly stated the reason your project may not be practical. I suspect that you will find that the insects and the piezos respond to *changes* in position and don't report position. In other words, a signal is given on and proportional to the change intensity or velocity but in the steady-state no signal is given. Run a finger along your arm with a light touch: you will sense the motion easily but not the steady touch. (This avoids nervous system overload otherwise every part of your body would be reporting constantly.)

In the same way a piezo crystal will give an output during change but if we draw the charge off by measuring it the voltage will drop to zero. To track position we would need to integrate the signal over time. This would not be an easy task with small signals and high impedances.

---

As a simple workable alternative I offer the following.

Standard industrial technique is mass flow measurement by hot wire. A quick web search gives the following from [TiePie Automotive](http://www.tiepie-automotive.com/en/Measurement_examples/Sensors/MAF_HotWire):

> he Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor measures the amount of passing air going through the air intake system. The sensor measures the amount of passing air with a resistive platinum wire that is placed in the air stream of the air intake system. The resistive wire has a positive temperature coefficient: the higher the temperature the higher the resistance of the wire. Electronics in the air flow meter sends an amount of current through the wire to warm it up. The wire temperature is kept constant. When more air passes the wire, more current is needed to keep the wire at a constant temperature. The current that flows though the wire is a measure for the amount of passing air. The current is measured by the electronics in the sensor and converted to a voltage at the output of the sensor. The engine control unit (ECU) calculates the amount of air going into the combustion chambers from this voltage.

[image]

*Source: [DieselNet](https://www.dieselnet.com/tech/sensors_air-mass-flow.php).*

> The hot wire air flow meter is the oldest type of anemometer, introduced into commercial automotive technology around 1985. The hot wire air flow meter (HLM) by Bosch proved highly popular. While no longer used in automotive applications, hot wire sensors are still installed in aeroplanes with piston engine drives.

The hot wire sensor has a simple functional principle and can operate without any moving parts. An electrically-heated wire (hot wire) is placed in the intake pipe after the air filter, transverse to the flow direction, Figure 1. A temperature sensor is installed upstream of the hot wire. The hot wire is then heated to a temperature higher than the air temperature determined by the temperature sensor. As the hot wire is cooled by the incoming air, the heating current must be increased to maintain a constant wire temperature. In this method, the heating current represents a direct measurement for the incoming air mass, independent of the air density. Thus, the reduced air density at high altitudes is elegantly compensated for.

Comment: I think this is the best most accurate solution so far. It maybe a matter of the OP's budget.